# Launch a thread on another Java VM instance and execute logic asynchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, transactions

### Background

- I am developing a web application running on an a JavaEE application server.

  - This application server has “thread canceling” feature. It terminates long-running (20min or more) threads for preventing resource starvation caused by deadlock or infinite loop.
  - This application server forbids to make child threads on servlets (this application server can write some logs for failure analysis, but these logs don’t work properly on child threads).
- My application has some time-consuming business logics (e.g. print itemized bills for all users). This kind of logics launched from a button on web pages.

  - Some business logics need 30 minutes or more to finish (it is enough for the browsers to get timeout error).
  - These logics should be executed only if preceding transaction finished successfully (e.g. the bills should not be printed if payments not recorded to DB successfully).

    - I know I can use messaging APIs (e.g. ActiveMQ with JMS API has transactional feature). But I want to avoid these solutions, because a global transaction between RDBMS and JMS will broken in some situations.

### Question

I think I have to run these logics on a thread on the other Java VM.
How can I launch a thread on another Java VM instance, and execute logic asynchronously?

Comment: Can your task be broken up into smaller pieces that run faster? Can you use an independent fixed-size threadpool to delegate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of further investigation, I found [JDBC Support feature in Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html) covers my requirements.
You can `INSERT` request for asynchronous business logic execution to RDBMS with outbound channel adapter, and run business logic on another JVM with inbound channel adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly launch a thread in another JVM. Since you are not using message queues, best I can think of using a RMI to call a method on another process on a different JVM which in turn can start the thread for you.